# escape characters not being preserved in json after ajax call

Tags: json

I have a web API that returns data to a web page in json format. One of the items in the json is: "Title":"blah blah blah". One title I encountered contains a quote being used for inches: "1" manual valve on group production..." When the API generates the json string, it adds all the necessary escape characters, and as far as I can tell, it looks good:

```
\"Title\":\"1\\\" manual valve on group production...\"
```

But then when it is retrieved by the javascript, the extra slash is taken away:

```
"Title":"1" manual valve on group production..."
```

I would expect at least one slash:

```
"Title":"1\" manual valve on group production..."
```

Needless to say it's screwing up the parsing of the JSON.

Here is my API code:

[Authorize]

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetTop3ReportCard([FromUri] int projectId, [FromUri] string othersIdCsv = null)
   {

if (projectId <= 0)
{
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Invalid project ID.");
}

//... 

Top3AndReportCard top3AndReportCard = GetTop3AndReportCard();

string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(top3AndReportCard);


return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, jsonString);
}
```

And here's the javascript that calls it:

```
        var projectId = store.get('filterProjectId');
        $.get('ReportConfig/GetJSONString', { projectID: projectId })

    .done(function (data) {
                ra.reportConfigPage.ReportJsonParsed = JSON.parse(data); // <-- Offending line
                ra.reportConfigPage.ReportJsonParsedOriginal = JSON.parse(data);
                ra.reportConfigPage.InitCommentBoxes();
            })

    .fail(function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('There was an error retrieving the JSON String:\n' +

        'jqXhr = ' + jqXhr + ', textStatus = ' + textStatus + ', errorThrown = ' + errorThrown);
                $("#spinning-loader").hide();
                $("#overlay").hide();
            });
```

It gets to the done() function in the ajax call but then crashes at the line marked "offending line".

Can anyone suggest why the slash is not being preserved when it returns from the AJAX call?

Comment: The character doesn't magically disappear. How did you inspect `data`? Could it be that `data` is already a JavaScript object? What does `typeof data` say?

Comment: I'm inspecting data in the Chrome console. I type 'data' and it gives me the content. typeof data tells me it's a string.